# SQL Query with optional aggregate and group possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to run a huge query with the option to sum up one column. I'm wondering if it would be possible to do something like the following:

```
declare @sumIt bit
set @sumIt = 1

select ID, Name, CASE WHEN @sumIt=1 THEN sum(Time) ELSE Time END [timeCol]     
from Visits
where ID = 123
Group by ID, Name, CASE WHEN @sumIt=1 THEN '' ELSE Time END
```

Right now I get an error:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'Visits.Time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What is your unique identifier in Visits?

Comment: @JohnDewey - In this query my unique identifier is not retrieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do the following:

```
declare @sumIt bit
set @sumIt = 1

select ID, Name,
       (CASE WHEN @sumIt=1 THEN sum(Time) ELSE min(Time) END) [timeCol]
from Visits
where ID = 123
Group by ID, Name, (CASE WHEN @sumIt=1 THEN '' ELSE Time END)
```

You can apply an aggregation function to the group by variables.  This isn't commonly done, but it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this works... I guess whether or not to actually do this is still the question.  I have a query that is over 150 lines that I don't want to duplicate to accomodate this one feature, but maybe for the sake of best practice I should.

Comment: BTW, I needed to change your example slightly from "Then ''" to "Then null" in the group clause to work with my case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this should work fine:

```
select ID, Name, sum([Time]) [timeCol]
from Visits
where ID = 123
AND @sumint = 1
Group by ID, Name
UNION ALL
select ID, Name, [Time] [timeCol]
from Visits
where ID = 123
AND @sumint = 0
Group by ID, Name, [Time]
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he doesn't want to have to maintain the huge query twice.  This doesn't really solve it, but honestly I can't think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could take the dynamic sql approach. Not crazy about it myself, i'd just use the IF

```
declare @sumIt bit, @sql VARCHAR(1000)
set @sumIt = 0

SET @sql = 'select ID, Name, ' + CASE WHEN @sumIt=1 THEN 'sum(Time)' ELSE 'Time' END  + ' [timeCol]
from Visits
where ID = 123
Group by ID, Name' + CASE WHEN @sumIt=1 THEN '' ELSE ',Time' END

EXEC @sql
```

Comment: I'd opt for two separate queries over string concatenation of SQL any day.